# Changing readOnly to true crashes the site in MS Chromium Edge

Tags: jquery, html, microsoft-edge, chromium

I have this odd bug that is happening in MS chromium Edge. The HTML part looks like this

```
<dl data-toggle="tooltip" title="Formula">
<dt>
    <label for="Login_Logout_Time">TimeZone
        <b>Early Departure or Late Arrival </b>
        <i>ONLY</i>
    </label>
</dt>
<dd>
    <input name="Login_Logout_Time" class="Login_Logout_Time" id="Login_Logout_Time"  data-toggle="popover" data-content="Invalid time entered" type="time" />
    <!--calling attendance to clear time for out of shift login logout -->
</dd>
```

Now when I try to change this field to make it editable or not using the following script the who site crashes.

```
$("#Login_Logout_Time").prop('readOnly', true)
```

or

```
document.getElementById("Login_Logout_Time").readOnly = true
```

I have no idea why it would do.

I thought this was my environment but am able to replicate it in fiddle too.

https://jsfiddle.net/abilash44/jw26ksbc/5/

In that link if you can run the above script in console, the site crashes. Any idea what is happening and how can this be avoided in MS chromium Edge?

Comment: Hmm aside from the time picker not being able to be edited. The site does not crash on my machine?

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback. I think the problem is with MS Chromium Edge. The site crashes only here. Seems to work fine on Google Chrome. I will file this under MS forum some where. My head went nuts when it started crashing for no reason.

Comment: I tried with your code in my Microsoft Edge Dev (Version 77.0.189.3) and it runs well. Microsoft Edge (Chromium) is in the development phase at present. You can try the latest version of Edge Dev and I think this will provide a better experience.

Comment: thanks @YuZhou . The problem only happens in Canary version. I moved to the dev version and learned a good lesson.